# file upload error messages are not displaying in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to insert data into database through a form. I'm uploading 2 image files, in database path of the files will be stored. I'm trying to do server side validation. when user does not upload a file  or when user is uploading wrong file type, an error messages should display and page should return to same page with no data inserted into database.
This is my view:

```
    <div class="main-panel">
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Add News & Event</h4>
                <p class="card-description"> </p>
                <?php echo validation_errors("<div class='alert alert-danger'>","</div>");?>

                  <?php if($failed = $this->session->flashdata('addNewsFailed')){
                      echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' ;
                      echo $failed;
                      echo '</div>';
                  }?>

                <form class="forms-sample" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputName1">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName1" value="<?php echo 
                      set_value("title");?>" name="title">
                  </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputName1">Sub Title</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName1" value="<?php echo set_value("sub");?>" name="sub_title">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputName1">Event Date</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName1" name="date"  value="<?php echo date('d - M - y ');//echo set_value("date");?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Feature Image</label>
                                    <div class="input-group col-xs-12">

                                        <input type="file" class="form-control file-upload-info"  placeholder="Upload Image" name="img" style="z-index: 9999; opacity: 0;" id="image">
                                        <div id="imageName"></div>
                                        <span class="input-group-append">
                                         <button class="file-upload-browse btn btn-info" type="button" style="position: absolute; left: 0; padding: 6px 23px;border-radius:3px;">Upload</button> </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php if(isset($upload_error)){

                                        echo $upload_error;

                                    }?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label> Banner Image</label>
                                    <div class="input-group col-xs-12">
                                        <input type="file" class="form-control file-upload-info" placeholder="Upload Image" name="banner" id="banner" style="opacity: 0; z-index: 9999;">
                                        <div id="bannerName"></div>
                                        <span class="input-group-append">
                                        <button class="file-upload-browse btn btn-info" type="button" style="position: absolute;left: 0;padding: 6px 23px;border-radius: 3px;">Upload</button></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php if(isset($upload_error1)){

                                        echo $upload_error1;

                                    }?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                         <span class="input-group-append">-->


                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleTextarea1">Text</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea1" rows="2" name="para"  value=""><?php echo set_value("para");?></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mr-2">Add</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-light">Cancel</button>
                </form>


              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

This is my controller:

```
public function addEvent()
{
    //load library
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper('form');

    //set rules for validation
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("title", "Title", "required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("date", "Event Date", "required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("para", "Text", "required");
    //template
    $this->output->set_template('admin_layout');
    //image upload
    $config = [
        'upload_path' => './uploads/',
        'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png',
    ];
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    //validation
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $post = $this->input->post();

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('img')) {
            $upload_error = $this->upload->display_errors();
            $this->load->view('dashboard/pages/forms/addEvent', compact('upload_error'));

        } else {
            $Feature1 = $this->upload->data();
            $image_path = base_url('uploads/' . $Feature1['raw_name'] . $Feature1['file_ext']);
            $post['image_path'] = $image_path;
        }

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('banner')) {
            $upload_error1 = $this->upload->display_errors();
            $this->load->view('dashboard/pages/forms/addEvent', compact('upload_error1'));

        } else {
            $carsousel = $this->upload->data();
            $banner = base_url('uploads/' . $carsousel['raw_name'] . $carsousel['file_ext']);
            $post['banner'] = $banner;
        }

        $this->load->model('loginmodel', 'addNews');
        $insert_id = $this->addNews->addNews($post);

        if ($insert_id) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("addNewsSuccess", 'News & Event Added Successfully');

            redirect('dashboard/update_news/' . $insert_id);
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("addNewsFailed", 'Failed');
            $this->load->view('dashboard/pages/forms/addEvent');
        }
    } else {
        $upload_error = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $this->load->view('dashboard/pages/forms/addEvent', compact('upload_error'));
    }
}
```

This is my model:

```
public function addNews($array)
{
    $this->db->insert('news', $array);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

My form validation are working perfectly but when user is uploading wrong file type or does not upload any file then file upload error message is not displaying and data is inserting into database the with both image field empty.

Comment: what is `compact('upload_error')`? and where you are passing your `$upload_error1` to your view?

Comment: @M.Hemant i'm passing `$upload_error1` below banner image. and `compact('upload_error')` is used for passing the upload error array to view page

Comment: Have you fixed it yet? In short - if your form validation passes you always perform an update regardless of what the uploads are doing. So you need to revisit your logic, if you haven't done so already.